# Check box not updating the DB using Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, model-view-controller, checkbox

I have a column called `vacant` in my `listings` table. It is a Boolean, but it is not updating when I check it and save. I have added it to my strong params in the `listings_controller.rb`, I made sure it's inside my loop, but still not sure.

schema.rb:

```
t.boolean  "vacant", default: false
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
  <label for="vacant_listing" class="general-text-label">Vacant Listing - Only check if apartment is vacant!</label><br>
  <%= f.check_box :vacant %> <br />
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your controller code?

Comment: @HubertJakubiak I figured out what was wrong. I have fields_for attributes and I added vacant inside of that. That was keeping the boolean from updating in the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I have fields_for attributes and I added vacant inside of that. That was keeping the boolean from updating in the DB.